# InfoPath 2010 form to send emails depending on drop-down value in the form and change views

Tags: infopath

1. I have a scenario where I am having a form with three different views. On first view I have two fields one is Read only and the other is drop-down box.
2. Drop-down box has 10 diff values like A, B C, D and each individual value is a team of which each one is having different permission groups in SharePoint.
3. When user selects any one of the value (for example A here) there should be a email sent to the group of people residing in 'A' with different view (view 2) of form where he can see one extra field apart from the two fields had in initial form.
4. Once the 'A' group person clicks on submit after filling third field which is a notes field, it will send email to initiator.
5. If he approves it a final form(view-3) with 10 different fields will be sent to the group again and they will fill the form and click on submit and an email with the form will be sent to initiator.
6. How to approach on this and how would I set up emails to be send on each explained case above and how to change the views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create a lookup list. This list contains the dropdown values with corresponding email address. So when initiator selects A, the email address of A will be pulled from the list.

Second, if you want the VIEW solution, you can create a dummy/hidden field where the value is 0 when the initiator is creating a new form. Now when Initiator submitted the form, create a rule that will set the dummy field to 1. This value ("1") will be tagged as submitted.

Use this value in creating a rule on form load. If dummy field = 1 then go to View 2.

Third, to get to View 3, you should put a rule that when Notes field is answered or a rule on submit button on VIEW 2 that will set dummy field to 2 when submitted.

Create another rule on form load: If dummy field = 2 then go to View 3

Comment: hi Mekalikot Thanks for your suggestion..i have tried using Calculated Column instead of Lookup column but my drop down value will be having a user group not an individual user.emails are going using the calculated column to required user group. But in view 2 I have to get the read only values in three of the fields which are filled in view1 . Do you know how could this be done?

Comment: for the 3 values, just set the properties of those 3 to Read Only in view 2. Right click and select text box properties.